# Анимация css в Qt. C++

Tags: c++, css, qt, css-animation

Возможно кто-то в курсе, каким образом можно создать анимацию, например плавное изменение цвета кнопки с помощью CSS, просто подключая, например:

```
   @keyframes move {
from, 
to {
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

Qt Не понимает, что требуется сделать. Заранее благодарен

Comment: Qt не поддерживает анимация в своих стилях (qss), но поддерживает анимацию через QAbstractAnimation, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/animation-overview.html, пример с движением https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-animation-moveblocks-example.html . Возможно будет полезно

Answer (score 1):

В Qt реализация **сss** (именуемая **qss**), нужен сугубо для быстрого редактирования существующих аттрибутов внешнего вида: цвет, ширина, высота и т.п. , но никак не для их анимации. Вот ссылки для ознакомления с qss: [Синтакс](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) [Референс](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html). Тут полная информация на что он способен.

Если нужны какие-либо анимации, используйте [QPropertyAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html). В сети полно примеров, как анимировать цвет фона, смещение геометрии при нажатии и прочего с помощью данного класса.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, **никак**. Библиотека Qt применяет не CSS, а [QSS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/QSS) для стилизации виджетов. И, так как активная разработка Qt Widgets не ведется, аналог анимаций CSS попросту не реализован...